# How to deploy service fabric application to remote server?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I tried publishing the Service fabric application from Visual studio to remote VM, but it didn't work. Is it possible to deploy the service fabric app from the visual studio to a remote VM? If yes please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

- Follow step 4 from [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-visualstudio-configure-secure-connections)

Manually edit the publishprofile xml file:

```xml
<ClusterConnectionParameters
ConnectionEndpoint="yourcluster:19000"
X509Credential="true"
ServerCertThumbprint="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
FindType="FindByThumbprint"
FindValue="9876543210987654321098765432109876543210"
StoreLocation="CurrentUser"
StoreName="My" />
```

Change the value of `yourcluster` into the machine name or IP of the VM.
Change the [thumbprint](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-service-fabric/bg-p/Service-Fabric) to match your cluster cert.

- Make sure to install the cluster certificate on your local machine too.